# Open play store from foreign country

Tags: google-play

I am in germany and need to access the india play store. How can I do this?

In Detail:
I need the google play store link for the app "Radio Remote Control"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://patrick-nagel.net/blog/archives/511

Comment: thx for the answer!
any chance to access other stores on pc/mac i browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourname.yourapp

worked for me. hope i can help others with that